# Urn with numbered balls. Let $X$ be a random variable to specify the numeric value of drawn ball

Tags: probability, random-variable

I am very new in probability and statistics, and I don't know if I can post here in cross-validated this very simple question. However I have this problem:

An urn has $10$ numbered balls such that

- $4$ of them have the number $0$
- $2$ of them have the number $1$
- $4$ of them have the number $2$

Let $X$ a random variable to specify the numeric value a ball $x$ drawn from the set of ten balls, $\Omega$. Determine the probability density function.

I have problems to identify the set of possible outcomes, I considered it as:
$\Omega = \left \{ 1, \ldots , 10 \right \}$
the possible outcome is the number of the ball extracted, even if I don't know what is the order of that balls.

If I understand, if I pass to the function $X$, one of the element in $\Omega$, one of that $10$ balls, that function would retrieves the number "printed" on that particular ball.

$\begin{array}{lcl}P(X=0) & = & P(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = 0\right \}) \\ & = & P(\left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \} ) \\ & = & \frac{4}{10} \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{lcl}P(X=1) & = & P(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = 1\right \}) \\ & = & P(\left \{ 5,6 \right \} ) \\ & = & \frac{2}{10} \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{lcl}P(X=2) & = & P(\left \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = 2\right \}) \\ & = & P(\left \{ 7,8,9,10 \right \} ) \\ & = & \frac{4}{10} \end{array}$

hence,

$p_X(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{rcl} \frac{4}{10} & \quad & 1 \le x \le 4 \\ \frac{2}{10} & \quad & 5 \le x \le 6 \\ \frac{4}{10} & \quad & 7 \le x \le 10 \\ 0 & \quad & x<1, x>10 \end{array} \right .$

I am really unsure about what I have done.
Please, can you give me any suggestions on how to set up correctly this problem and correct any error? Many thanks!

Comment: Your answer is fine except for the values that $X$ can take on.  In your expression at the bottom you seem to be saying it can be any integer between 1 and 10, but it has to be a 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit off, your density function, for example, cannot be correct as

$$\sum_\omega p_X(\omega) = 4\cdot {4\over 10}+2\cdot {2\over 10}+4\cdot{4\over 10}$$

You have correctly identified that $\Omega = [10]$ with the uniform measure is the right call, however, the way the question is phrased you want $X(i)=`` \text{the number printed on ball }i\text{."}$ But you want $p_X(\omega)={1\over 10}$ for all $\omega$ because this is the density function, and all balls are equally likely, i.e. this is **not** about the probability of the **value** of $\omega$ it is the probability of picking a given ball. That is $P(X=X(\omega_0))\ne p_X(\omega_0)$ since $X^{-1}(X(\omega_0))$ is a full set which is probably bigger than just $\{\omega_0\}$.

Comment: so the $x$ is one of the 10 balls.  $$\begin{array}{rcl} x & 1 & \ldots & 10 \\ P(X=x) & \frac{1}{10} & \ldots & \frac{1}{10} \end{array}$$  but, what I have to do if I want to calculate the probability to draw a ball labelled with 2?

Comment: @JB-Franco no, $p_X(x) = {1\over 10}$ here $x\in\Omega$ not $\{0,1,2\}$ remember $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$. I think the notation is what is confusing you, in $p_X(x)$ we have $x\in\Omega$ (i.e. the domain) in $P(X=x)$ we have $x\in\Bbb R$, the target space, not the domain.

Comment: @JB-Franco I have edited my own notation to reflect more strongly where the argument lives, here $\omega$ is used to represent something in $\Omega$ to avoid confusion with values of $X$ which are in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: so the $P(X = x)$ I wrote in the first post is right, but it is wrong write the sets as $P(\left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \})$ because there isn't any order. Only the part of $p_X(x)$ is wrong.

Comment: @JB-Franco yeah, basically. The $p_X(x)$ is the **density** of an element of the domain whereas $P(X=x)$ is the probability you take a particular **value** in the range. What you really meant was $P(1\le X\le 4) = {4\over 10}$ which is a statement about the probability function, not about the probability density function.

Comment: There are errors in my problem, and we are reasoning on them. I think that write $P(1 \le X \le 4)$ is wrong, because it seems that we are labelling the balls considering the position 1 to 10 and $P(1 \le X \le 4)$ seems to mean the probability to draw a ball in the positions from 1 to 4 is 4/10. And in addition, to avoid confusion, I add all the points of my exercise, and then we will according to edit the original post. points: a) determine the probability function of X; b) determine the distribution function of X and represent it graphically; c) $E(X)$; d) $P(X=2|X\ \le 2)$

Comment: @JB-Franco usually when there are substantial changes to a question, it is proper to create a new question and reference the old one to not cause issues with already posted answers.

Comment: for probability function of X I consider the following: $$p_X : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1] \quad \mbox{ such that } \quad p_X(x) = P(X=x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: @JB-Franco that's incorrect, the probability density function is denoted by the lower-case letter $p$ and is $p_X:\Omega\to [0,1]$ so that $\displaystyle P(X=x) = \int_{X^{-1}(x)}p_X(\omega)dP(\omega)$.

Comment: I quote what it is written in my book: Assigned a discrete random variable $X$, with distinct values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, \ldots$, we call probability function of X, a function $p_X(\cdot)$ defined on the set of real numbers and to values in the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @JB-Franco yes, but you're confusing the range values with the domain values, (in this case both are real numbers). $p$ is defined on $\Omega$, not on $\{0,1,2\}$, in particular $p_X(x)$ cannot be $P(X=x)$ because the $x$ in $p_X(\cdot)$ is a domain value and the $x$ in $P(X=\cdot)$ is a range value. Your book isn't wrong, but what you wrote in your previous comment **is** wrong. You cannot use the same symbol $x$ for two different concepts in the same formula. In this particular case, note $0\not\in\Omega$ so $p_X(0)$ makes no sense, and $3\in\Omega$ so $p_X(3)={1\over 10}\ne 0=P(X=3)$ does!

Comment: Sorry, if I continue to ask! Ok, but, what I say now is, that $3$ that you are written what is it? The ball number $3$? But, the balls have been labelled  only with $\left \{ 0,1,2 \right \}$. Or not?

Comment: @JB-Franco I think I see your confusion, there are $10$ balls, this is the third ball, it has label $0$, since you have already established you label the first $4$ balls $0$ and the next two $1$ and the last $4$ with $2$. It is important not to confuse the ball's **index** with its **label**. If it helps, try visualizing things as ordered pairs $(1,0), (2,0),\ldots (10,2)$ where $(m,n)$ indicates ball $m$ is labeled with the number $n$.

Comment: the domain values are $\in \Omega$ and they are the balls from 1 to 10, the range contains the values of the labels $\left \{ 0, 1, 2 \right \}$

Comment: @JB-Franco yes, exactly. And $p_X(\cdot)$ takes domain values and $P(X=\cdot)$ takes range values.

Comment: so $X$ takes one of the values in the domain as argument, and retrieves a value from the range. for istance, asking what is the label of the ball drawn from position 2, and receiving as answer that it is 0, it is the same of passing 2 to the random variable $X$, and see that the result of that function is 0. $X(2)=0$. Instead, passing the range value $0$ to the function $P$, it retrieves a value within $[0,1]$, i.e. $P(X=0)=\frac{4}{10} \in [0,1]$. What is the probability that the event "the ball $\omega$ with label 0" happens, considering that there are 10 balls and 4 of them have label 0?

Comment: I would relabel that "**a** ball, $\omega$, with label $0$" since there are multiple such balls.